# sympy piecewise:I want to check piecewise & piecewise rhs value

Tags: python, algorithm, sympy

sympy piecewise:I want to check

I would appreciate any advice you could give me.

```
from sympy import *
var('x')
p1=Piecewise((0,x< -1),(1,x>=5))
p2=Piecewise((0,x< -1),(1,5<=x))
p3=Piecewise((1,x>= 5),(0,x<-1))
```

i want

output example

p2 : Piecewise((0,x< -1),(1,5<=x))) ---> Piecewise((0,x<-1),(?,x<=5),(1,5<=x))

p3 : Piecewise((1,x>= 5),(0,x<-1)) ---> Piecewise((0,x<-1),(1,5<=x ))

It seems to me that cond alone would be a good idea.

ref

Piecewise( (expr,cond), (expr,cond), ... )

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/functions/elementary/piecewise.py

## (20220317)

I like to make a drawing.

①　I want Piecewise rhs (value : -1,5)

i want  edge point x coordinate value

[image]

```
from sympy import *
var('x')
p1=Piecewise((0,x< -1),(1,x>=5))
p2=Piecewise((0,x< -1),(1,5<=x))
p3=Piecewise((1,x>= 5),(0,x<-1))
plot(15,p1,p2,p3,(x,-10,10))
```

ref

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/0647f74edc33b09d8add749c72b49c8715d7da4a/sympy/plotting/plot.py#L1649-L1855

Comment: Hi! Could you please rephrase? I have no idea what the question means.

Answer (score 1):

The last argument to Piecewise, with condition `True` will provide a value if none of the previous conditions are satisfied:

```
>>> Piecewise((1, x < -1), (2, x > 5), (3, True)).subs(x, 0)
3
```